# Web site works in dev mode; when deployed on IIS causes Security Exception

Tags: asp.net, iis, trust, securityexception

My ASP.NET web site works fine in development/debug mode, but when I publish it, I'm getting the following error:

> **Security Exception**
>
> **Description:** The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

I've googled for this error, and it comes up plenty, and ll the answers say the same thing: put

```
<trust level="Full" originUrl=""/>
```

in the web.config file.

Ya, ya, ya.  Thing is, I've checked that this line is in every web.config file I could find - the app itself, plus the framework\version\config\web.config files, both 32- and 64-bit (I'm running Windows 7).

There must be another secret switch somewhere - but what?

**EDIT**

At the request of a commenter, let me clarify: the page that causes the crash has a control from the [AJAX Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act.ashx).  If I comment out the ToolkitScriptManager and CalendarExtender controls, the page works fine, even under IIS.

Error stack trace (in case it helps):

```
[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
System.Reflection.Assembly._GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +0
System.Web.UI.NamespaceTagNameToTypeMapper.GetControlType(String tagName, IDictionary attribs, Boolean throwOnError) +209
System.Web.UI.TagPrefixTagNameToTypeMapper.System.Web.UI.ITagNameToTypeMapper.GetControlType(String tagName, IDictionary attribs) +210
System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.GetControlType2(String tagName, IDictionary attribs, Boolean fAllowHtmlTags) +242
System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.GetControlType(String tagName, IDictionary attribs, Boolean fAllowHtmlTags) +17
System.Web.UI.RootBuilder.GetChildControlType(String tagName, IDictionary attribs) +22
System.Web.UI.ControlBuilder.CreateChildBuilder(String filter, String tagName, IDictionary attribs, TemplateParser parser, ControlBuilder parentBuilder, String id, Int32 line, VirtualPath virtualPath, Type& childType, Boolean defaultProperty) +119
System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessBeginTag(Match match, String inputText) +605
System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding) +1334
```

Comment: Is ASP.net installed/enabled in your IIS installation?

Comment: what operation are you trying to perform?  Is this on initial page load or at some other point in your application.  what code do you have in application_start?

Comment: @Paddy - I didn't know it was possible to disable ASP.net on IIS.  Where do I find that setting (Windows 7)?

Comment: @matt-dot-net - The initial page works fine, but when I go onto a page that has an AJAX extender, that's when I get the error.

Comment: @Paddy - aspnet_regiis.exe /u

Comment: @Shaul - are you saying that if you remove the ajax extender the page works?  What extender is it and what are you trying to do?  Might I suggest that you post some code or the stack trace from your exception?

Comment: @matt-dot-net - if I comment out the ToolkitScriptManager and the CalendarExtender, the page works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I came here from a dark place with legacy code and when I clicked the answer link i got a 404.

Felt a bit like: https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/wisdom_of_the_ancients.png

Anyways, Way back machine to the rescue:

https://web.archive.org/web/20100329104446/http://dbvt.com/blog/post/AspNetHostingPermission-Security-Exception-Fix-with-Ajax-in-IIS7.aspx